# Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "217" already exists

Tags: magento2.2.3, data-migration

This Error is coming on **Magento 2.2.3** frontend after Migrating the data from **Magento 1.9**

> Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "217" already exists.

This Error is coming on few Products, not on all products.

I have applied few fixes from google, but nothing is working.

Comment: Please check duplicate `product_id` exist in database or not.

Comment: This 217 is related to product id 541. and there is only 1 product entry for 541 in catalog_product_entity.

Comment: You check for product id 217?

Comment: its 1 row for 217 too.

Comment: Compare product 217 and 541. Which value is common. First, check `url_key`.

Comment: it start working itself !!!

Comment: Okay. It is good for you.

Comment: Solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121021/magento2-products-errors-item-magento-catalog-model-product-interceptor-with/299081#299081

Answer (score 0):

Lookup product with id **217** in Magento and re-save them manually. Rinse repeat, until all errors are of this type are gone from exeption.log.

This worked for me with same error. I also imported products from **Mageneto 1.9**.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it turns out for me it was nothing to do with catalog_inventory_stock_item at all, my issue actually lay in the catalog_product_entity_varchar table. What caused this for me is that the product I was saving programmatically was saving the data under a different store id. Try doing

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id = {entity id that is in your error};
```

look through the resulting rows, if any of them have a store_id other than 0 (or whatever your base store id is) then make a backup of the table then try removing those and refresh the cache then the page. If you have the issue I had, it'll go away.