# Wishlist function does not work - Item (Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item) with the same ID "5192" already exists

Tags: magento2, wishlist

We are having an issues with wishlist function. Products are not added to the wishlist.

In ***system.log*** and ***exception.log*** we get the following messages, when a customer click on ***"add to wishlist"*** in frontend:

***system.log***

```
[2020-01-26 17:32:00] main.CRITICAL: Item (Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item) with the same ID "5192" already exists. [] []
```

***Exception.log***

```
[2020-01-26 17:20:08] main.CRITICAL: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at /home/xxxxx/www/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:310)"} []
```

***customer/section/load/***
message: "Item (Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item\Interceptor) with the same ID "13620" already exists."

Does any one know how can we fix this issue?

Best regards,
Jesper

Answer (score 1):

Hey there it seems sometimes ago we also received the same ID “” already exists but for Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/299081/66041

Try using this maybe it will help..